# PEEK memory addresses for keybord keys pressed

Tags: dos, quickbasic

I have Microsoft Quick BASIC 4.5 running on a DOS 5.0 computer.

I have been able to `PEEK` the memory to see when special keyboard keys like Num Lock, Caps Lock, Insert, and others are pressed:

```
DEF SEG = 0
x = PEEK(&H418)
Print x
```

When I print `x` I get the following values for the following keys:

```
Right Shift = 1
Left Shift = 2
Ctrl = 4
Alt = 8
Scroll Lock = 16
Num Lock = 32
Caps Lock = 64
Insert = 128
```

But what memory segment (`DEF SEG`) and memory address `PEEK`(?) do I use to "see" when the A key, or B key, or number key, or any other key is pressed?

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QBasic/Advanced_Input . Using Inkey$ might do what you want.

Comment: Try using INP(&H60) to get keyboard codes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a location to check for those keys. You might be able to use inkey$ for that. Together with Peek($h418) you should be able to get the current keypresses.